# Как ограничить FlowPane при добавлении в неё объектов?

Tags: javafx

Есть вот такая FlowPane: [image: Есть вот такая FlowPane]

Когда в неё добавляется много объектов, то происходит вот такое: [image: Проблема =(]

Как сделать так, что бы объекты не могли её расширять, а когда не будет хватать места, появится ScrollBar или как его там и можно будет прокручивать её дальше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть имеется `FlowPane` с `fx:id="myFlowPane"`.

1. В файл разметки вставляете строку `<ScrollPane fx:id="myScrollPane"/>` (как дочерний элемент корневого).
2. В контроллер добавляете поле `@FXML ScrollPane myScrollPane;`.
3. В метод `initialize()` контроллера добавляете строку `myScrollPane.setContent(myFlowPane);`. Тут же можно необходимым образом настроить Ваш `ScrollPane`.

Comment: Я сперва не много не понял, но потом до меня дошла суть. Я создал ScrollPane и сделал для него дочерним FlowPane и получилось то, что нужно было. Боже, как просто. Весь день промучился.